# average of only numerical part of cells, avoid any letters

Tags: excel, vba, formula, average

I am trying to work a formula to tell me the average of a cell that contain numbers but also letters.

```
Price
$486.5/mt,
$287/mt,
$286.75/mt,
$286.5/mt,
$286.75/mt,
```

So each cell contains one of the above for example cell F2 contains '$486.5/mt,'. My question is what formula can I use to only return number average. For now, the average formula doesn't work even work. I tried using "LEFT" formula, but that won't work because the $ sign comes before the value.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: is it always a `$` infront and a `/`after?

Comment: @krib Hey, yes there is. Since I directly import the data from another workbook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this without VBA, using an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Array-formulas-8ff8257a-b28e-4e81-b4f8-30f793412dfa) like this one:

```
=AVERAGE(VALUE(MID(K18:K22,2,LEN(K18:K22)-5)))
```

(values in K18:K22)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
Public Function NumbersOnly(str As String) As Single
  Dim c As String
  Dim nIndex As Integer
  Dim sResult As String

  For nIndex = 1 To Len(str)
    If IsNumeric(Mid$(str, nIndex, 1)) Or Mid$(str, nIndex, 1) = "." Then
      sResult = sResult & Mid$(str, nIndex, 1)
    End If
  Next
  NumbersOnly = Val(sResult)
End Function
```

and then the formula for cell `F3` would be:

`=NumbersOnly(F2)`

Comment: Don't use a `Single` as the returntype. Use a `Double` over a `Single` instead. You could get an inaccurate number returned with a `Single` (since it is less precise). For this problem particularly though, `Currency` would likely be ideal.

Comment: Hi, this looks interesting. So I insert this as a macro, and then enter the formula into cell F3? Because when i try run the macro i've given an error. Anyone know what it could be?

Comment: You will get an error if the cell has more than one period... but that was not the case in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a similar approach to braX, this function will explicitly convert strings that are in the predefined format ($.../...) which will prevent any issues from an improperly formatted (or otherwise invalid) string. This allows greater control over the return.

```
Public Function GetAmountFromString(ByVal InputString As String) As Variant
    If InputString Like "$*/*" Then
        Dim ProcessedString As String
        ProcessedString = Replace(InputString, "$", vbNullString)

        Dim SplitString As Variant
        SplitString = Split(ProcessedString, "/")

        ' Explicitly convert String to Currency.
        GetAmountFromString = CCur(SplitString(0))
    Else
        GetAmountFromString = vbNullString
    End If
End Function
```

This function will first check for the format. As long as the input is in the correct format it will then replace the '$' symbol with a null string. Finally, it will split the string into two parts using the '/'. It will return a `Currency` version of the value before the '/' symbol.

In the event of an improper input it will return a null string. This can be customized as you wish (you can replace `vbNullString` with `"ThisIsAnInvalidInput"` and it will still work just fine.

To use this function, add it to your VBProject, and then use the function `=GetAmountFromString(Cell)` in your worksheet.

You can also use this function from other subroutines (if, for example, you wanted to use the function within a subroutine that averaged valid values only).